# How can Facebook's photo upload application access the local harddrive?

Tags: applet, client-side

I didn't think it was possible for client side applications to access the harddrive? How can this application do it?

Can a signed Java applet get access to your peripherals? I know that flash can...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Facebook uploader is a Java applet, which requires your approval before allowing access to your PC.

Comment: Can a signed Java applet get access to your peripherals? I know that flash can...

Comment: A signed Java applet can do anything a standalone Java application can do. So yes, you can print, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for CLIENT side apps to access your local disk, but not SERVER side. The client side is executing on the local machine after all.

So, for example, a PHP/ASP/JSP/etc. script can't access your files, but a Javascript or Java applet *potentially* can(after being accepted by any security implemented to prevent malicious client side scripts from accessing your files; usually in the form of an 'are you sure you really want to let this script do this?').